# HTML Select "Selected" attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm generating a list of colors with Angular, using the following code:

```
<select id="color" ng-model="bgCol">
    <option ng-selected="{{ind == 0}}" ng-repeat="(ind, color) in colors" value="{{ind}}">{{color.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And "colors" is an array of objects:

```
colors = [{
    "name":"Red",
    "color":"C00"
}]
```

But none of the options are being selected, instead an empty option is selected by default, and deleted when the selection is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should consider

1. Do not use `ng-repeat` for adding options to `select`
2. In your `json`, remove quotes from the `key`. It should be `name:"Red"` and not `"name":"Red"`.
3. Add a `ng-model` attribute to the `select` tag and declare it to select a default option rather than a blank at page load.

See the code below

```
<select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-options="color.name as color.color for color in colors"></select>
```

And declare `selecteditem` in the controller as

```
 $scope.selecteditem = $scope.colors[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) where they provide a nearly identical example to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Managed to get it to work using `ng-options="color.name for color in colors track by color.color"` and `ng-init="bgCol = colors[random()]"`